# input of type file re-sizes table out of its boundaries

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

I have a input field of type file:

```
<input class="textbox" type="file" tabindex="1" value="" size="40" name="file">
```

In case you wonder, `textbox` class is just:

```
background: rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.95) none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
```

Whenever I browse and select a file my file input will re-size itself out of the boundaries of the table and also make the table re-size it self outside its limit going over the other table.

How can I limit the input of type file so it doesn't re-sizes my table?

When the input is not used at the far right side you can see a small space between both tables about 10 pixels or so...

[image: when it's ok]

Now when its broken you can see it overlaps with the other table and the above shown space is gone.

[image: broken without max-width]

with max-width still breaks the table but keeps the input controlled:

[image: broken with max-width]

I tried to use max-width to solve it but it didn't work, whenever I select a file it will just overflow.

The issue happens with Firefox, not sure if other browsers have the same effect.

Comment: what's the full css you're using to ensure it doesn't overflow?

Comment: File input controls are dealt with differently by different browsers; if you want anything resembling “control” over how they behave within your layout, then I suggest to implement some custom styling along the lines of what is outlined here, http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/

Comment: @Onimusha that was the entire css there is nothing else in it

Comment: @CBroe that looks nice I will check it out

Comment: Ok, I read in the Q that you used max-width but I don't see it. Please see my answer. I tested on firefox and overflow disappeared with max-width

Comment: Please recreate your error on jsfiddle or similar because there's not enough technical information on your error in the question. It's just a guessing game right now

Comment: Well using `table-layout: fixed;` solved the issue, still have to check other chrome and ie to see if they are fine with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below css fixed it and did not cause any issues with other browsers:

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

Answer (score 1):

For

```
<input class="textbox" type="file" tabindex="1" value="" size="40" name="file">
```

You need in your css:

```
.textbox{
    max-width: 100%;
    background: rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.95) none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
}
```

Google chrome already truncates overflowing text. Firefox will need `max-width: 100%;` on `input[type=file]` for long file names

---

Width max-width on firefox:

[image]

Without max-width on firefox:

[image]

Comment: [The overflow of the table continues but the control is kept in size but only happens when the file is selected, I forgot to post this image, **but have updated it to the question**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/17lYU.jpg)